# Linq to Entities: cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#

I am trying to execute this query, but I am getting an error: cannot be translated into a store expression.

If I can't do it this way how can I implement it? I am using C#.

I am trying to display training records if the date taken is not this year. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
tr =  from l in t.Trainees
      where !db.UserTrainings.Any(ut => ut.Trainees.TraineeId == l.TraineeId &&
                                        ut.Passed == true &&
                                        ut.DateTaken >= l.DateEnded.Value.AddYears(-1)) 
      ...... rest of the query.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not had a chance to use `EntityFunctions` before, but I believe that it could be used to solve your problem.

Try replacing `l.DateEnded.Value.AddYears(-1)` with `EntityFunctions.AddYears(l.DateEnded, -1)`. The method is documented [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412530(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Ah. I'm not sure how to do that in .NET 3.5. I strongly recommend upgrading if possible (EF, in particular, has many, many enhancements).